# Flutter convert List<dynamic> to use in builder

Tags: flutter, dart

There is data coming from API looks like this

```
"doc_list": [
 {
   "text": "test1",
   "date_added": "2022-02-20",
   "added_by_user_id": "10",
 },
 {
   "text": "test2",
   "date_added": "2022-02-21",
   "added_by_user_id": "10",
 },
]
```

In my Model I load this data to a dynamic list like this

```
List<dynamic>? org_doc_list = [];
```

Now when I print the data inside widget I see the data like following

```
[
 {
  text: test1,
  date_added: 2022-02-20,
  added_by_user_id: 10,
 },
 {
  text: test2,
  date_added: 2022-02-21,
  added_by_user_id: 10,
 }
]
```

All quotation marks are removed and I think it became a string. How can I convert this to use with `ListView.builder()` inside a widget

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like a regular dictionary / instance of **Map<String, dynamic>** inside your ***ListView.builder***, as in:

```dart
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: org_doc_list.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       
      var org_doc = org_doc_list[index];
      
      // access properties by their key
      var text = org_doc['text'];
      var dateAdded = org_doc['date_added'];
   }
)
```